# compare the sum of characters in a 2d array of strings

Tags: java

I want to print from my program the index of the column that has the highest number of characters in a 2d array of strings

```
public static int columns(String [][] matrix) {
    int numCol = matrix[0].length;
    int indexCol = -1;
    for(int col = 0; col < numCol; col++) {
        int count = 0;
        int countEach = 0;
        for(String[] row : matrix) {
            count += row[col].length();
            if(count > countEach){
                countEach = count;
            }

            System.out.println("count one by one (rows) : " + countEach +" "+"Column :" + col);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("SumChar : " + count +" " + "column : "+col + "###############");
    }
    System.out.println("Index of the highest array of characters by columns : ");
    return indexCol;
}
```

So far, my code looks like this but I'm stuck on how to compare my results, Can somebody kindly give me an explanation on how to proceed? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your if clause and in the location of your variable `countEach`. `countEach` will be set to `0` every iteration of your outer loop, making your if clause always true, and therefore doing a useless work. What you want is to use `countEach` as a variable that keeps the value of the biggest sum of chars that some column has. With this, you can then pass the if clause to the outer loop and add to it the update of the column index that has more chars.

Check the modifications bellow:

**FULL CODE**

```
public static int columns(String [][] matrix) {
    int numCol = matrix[0].length;
    int indexCol = -1;
    int countEach = 0; // Put countEach outside the for loop

    for(int col = 0; col < numCol; col++) {
        int count = 0;

        for(String[] row : matrix) {
            count += row[col].length();

            System.out.println("count one by one (rows) : " + count +" "+"Column :" + col);
        }

        // Move if clause to here
        if(count > countEach){
            countEach = count;
            indexCol = col; // Update column index with more chars
        }

        System.out.println("SumChar : " + count +" " + "column : "+col + "###############");
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("Index of the highest array of characters by columns : ");
    return indexCol;
}
```

Comment: The full program has another matrix [][] of numbers , and my variable was outside the loop , I don't know how I missed the fact that i should have had the same for the matrix [][] of strings , thank you very much , this is a reminder I have to be more carefull on where I initiate my variables !